# Visually-identical characters in Unicode

Tags: unicode, similarity

I want to find visually identical characters for a specific character in Unicode.
I know how to find canonical or compatibility decompositions of a character; but they do not give me what I want.
I want to find characters that are visually identical (not similar), and their only difference can be their sizes.

for example I want : (s,S), or (S,S) (whose code points are different).
I do not want (ß, β), or (e, é).

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Unicode does not specify the appearance of characters. That's a font issue. (The standard uses _representative_ images, but they are not part of the standard.) For instance, do you want capital I and digit 1 and lower case l all together? In some fonts they are identical and in other fonts they are all distinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a particular character, you could start from annotations in the code charts in the Unicode standard. The annotations often refer to other characters for various reasons, including similarity or identity of shape. But the annotations are not meant to cover everything.

You could also draw your character at http://shapecatcher.com/ and ask it to recognize it. You often get a long list of visually similar alternatives.

As @TedHopp writes in his comment, visual identity is font-dependent. For example, “s” and “S” need not be identical in shape; in most fonts, they are not – the basic form is the same, but there are various differences in stroke width variation, curvature, serifs, etc. However, some characters can be expected to be visually identical in any font that contains them, such as Latin capital A, Greek capital alpha Α, and Cyrillic capital А.

You did not specify the purpose of the study, but you might be doing something that has been carried out to some extent by the Unicode Consortium. See [UTR #6](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/), *Unicode Security Considerations*, which also contains references to related work, including [UTS #9](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39/), *Unicode Security Mechanisms*, which contains confusables.txt, Recommended confusable mapping for IDN (i.e., for a particular context, but it may be of interest for other purposes as well).

Comment: Good explanation!

There are also characters that are visually identical but that are different graphemes or that have different sounds or roles.  For example, Latin "H" (as in "Hot") versus Cyrillic "H" (as in "неплохо" - the first letter pronounced like Latin "N").

It might be helpful for other readers to know that Unicode characters represent "graphemes" but not their *meanings*, and certainly not "glyphs."