# What Is The Difference Between u+00d0 and u+0110?

Tags: unicode

They both render as Ð (And the other as Đ). I think that pretty much sums it up. Is there an inherent difference?

Comment: Related, arguably duplicate since the answer also covers this issue: [Visually-identical characters in Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260890/visually-identical-characters-in-unicode)

Comment: One is eth and the other is dyet. There's no guarantee they'll render the same in all fonts, and their lowercase equivalents are much more obviously different.

Answer (score 3):

They render slightly differently, or similarly, depending on your system.. Char `u+0110` is "Latin Capital Letter Eth" and char `u+00d0` is "Latin Capital Letter D with stroke". Try opening these pages in different tabs and switch back and forth, the example is rendered slightly differently.

[Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH' (U+00D0)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d0/index.htm)

[Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE' (U+0110)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0110/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

They render very similarly<sup>1</sup>, but they are different characters, and the lowercase version of those uppercase letters render very differently<sup>1</sup>.

For comparison:

| Name | Capital | Small |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Latin Letter Eth | Ð ([U+00D0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d0/index.htm)) | ð ([U+00F0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f0/index.htm)) |
| Latin Letter D with Stroke | Đ ([U+0110](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0110/index.htm)) | đ ([U+0111](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0111/index.htm)) |
| Latin Letter African D / Latin Letter D with Tail | Ɖ ([U+0189](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0189/index.htm)) | ɖ ([U+0256](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0256/index.htm)) |

<sup>*1) Depends on the font, of course.*</sup>

---

*Credit: This answer is mostly a refinement/combination of the [answer by doublesharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315392/5221149) and the [comment by John Montgomery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315353/what-is-the-difference-between-u00d0-and-u0110#comment115471382_65315353).*