# String.getBytes return the substitution character for a character that should be valid

Tags: java, string

I am trying to encode a character Đ (U+00D0 in unicode) in CP1147 (french EBCDIC + euro)

```
        String value = "Đ";
        byte[] sendRecord = value.getBytes("CP1147");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : sendRecord) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        var formattedHexResult =  sb.toString();
        Assertions.assertEquals("3F", formattedHexResult);
```

the character  Đ exists in CP1147, I should get X'AC' but I get X'3F' which is the substitution character

i have tried to understand how the getBytes works but it is way above my level

the charset used is sun.nio.cs.ext.IBM1147 and it includes u00D0

What is blocking the conversion?

Comment: In the code you posted you have U+0110 "capital D with stroke" not U+00D0 "capital Eth". Although they look (very!) similar these are not the same character; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315353/what-is-the-difference-between-u00d0-and-u0110 . And I wasn't aware either was used in French (or France). Which do you have in your actual source code?

Comment: The source is the capital D, with a stroke, it is from an OCR  foreign document.

Answer (score 1):

The character you have pasted is not the character you think it is.

```
    String value = "Đ";
    byte[] bexp = { (byte)0xAC };
    String v2 = new String(bexp, "CP1147");
    System.out.println("expected: " + v2 + " = " + value + " " + v2.equals(value));
```

That results in.

> expected: Ð = Đ false

As pointed out, you have pasted C490 ( capital letter D with a stroke in UTF8 ) which doesn't exist in CP1147 but you are expecting C390 ( capital letter ETH in UTF8 ) which does exist.

```
    public static void pp(byte[] bs){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bs) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String value = "Đ";
        System.out.println(value);
        byte[] ok = value.getBytes("UTF8");

        byte[] bexp = { (byte)(16*10 + 12) };
        String v2 = new String(bexp, "CP1147");

        pp(v2.getBytes("UTF8"));
        pp(v2.getBytes("CP1147"));
        pp(value.getBytes("UTF8"));
        pp(value.getBytes("CP1147"));

    }
```

Using that I get the following output.

> Đ
> C390
> AC
> C490
> 3F

Comment: BTW `(byte)(16*10 + 12)` can also be represented as `(byte) 0xAC`

Comment: @user85421 thanks, I knew I didn't have to explicitly write out all powers of 16 but I wasn't sure how. :D